# How do I send a POST Request to Google Translate Api using a C# WebClient?

Tags: c#, webclient, google-translate

I googled now for almost an hour and can't find anything that would help me out. I'm a beginner programer and took the course over from TeamTreeHouse with Serialization in C#. Here I also learned how to use the WebClient.

Now I thought a good practice Project would be to make a Translate app that sends to google the user input in a POST Request and Google returns the answer as Json which I deserialize.

Problem is I read through the documentation of the api but I'm so confused of what I should send exactly to google and really how to do this?

I know the method `webclient.Headers.Add(arguments here)` , but I really don't know what else it needs.

You can find an example over here:

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text

> https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2   Three query
>   parameters are required with each translation request:
>
> **Target language**: Use the target parameter to specify the language you
>   want to translate into. **Source text string**: Use the q parameter to
>   specify each text string to translate. **API key**: Use the key parameter
>   to identify your application. If you are using OAuth 2.0 service
>   account credentials (recommended), do not supply this parameter.

So problem is there is no placeholder in that example URL where I could put my api key + soure text string an Target language.

So what exactly should I send to google so it knows what I want and returns me the JSON file?

Maybe anyone could help me out. And I know there is an official Library for exactly this but I want to practice serialization and using web scraping with the WebClient class so I want to do it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate#body.QUERY_PARAMETERS

says use query parameters q, target, key, etc.
So your URL should be something like https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=[yourAPIkey]&target=language

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for. It's hard to google and search for the right "thing" when you are just starting out.

Answer (score 6):

You specifically asked about a POST.

1. You can use this url:

   https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY_KEY

Of course, replace MY_KEY with your key.

2. Add a header for the content type:

   application/json; charset=utf-8
3. Format your text and target language as JSON and write it to your request stream:

   {"q":"Team work is a major progress maker at this location, it appears that everyone is willing to help when they can.","target":"fr"}